# Reuse file uploaded via (File|Image|Whatever)Field in another node

Tags: 7, files, media

I noticed the existence of this file_usage table in D7's database and I was wondering if it's possible to link in a new node the same file I uploaded using a file field in a previously created node. This seems logical to me, yet I can't seem to find a way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

The [FileField Sources](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) module expands the file field widget and allows the user to select new or existing files through additional means, including  re-use files by an auto-complete textfield, attach server-side files uploaded via FTP, transfer files from a remote server (cURL required) and select existing files through the [IMCE file browser](http://drupal.org/project/imce).

The [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) module (2.x) provides and additional file field widget which use its media browser to upload or select a (media) file.

Answer (score 1):

I know this an old thread, but https://drupal.org/project/media does what you want. (or at least the goal of media is to do what you want.)

If you can use media 2.x (as I write this there are several show stoppers with wysiwyg editors and 2.x) I would go that route.